# Proving that 0 is the greatest lower bound for this sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I'm ultimately trying to show a sequence converges to $0$, and I'm doing so by comparing it to another sequence, $n|c|^n$ where $|c|<1.$ I've already shown it's bounded and monotone decreasing past a certain point, so the monotone convergence theorem says it converges to its greatest lower bound. I know this is $0$, but I'm not able to prove it. All of the terms of the sequence are positive, so $0$ is *a* lower bound, but the leap to showing that it's the greatest of those has me pulling at my hair. I keep running into the product log function which I won't be able to use, and there seems to be no avoiding that.

Comment: So if you can compare it to $n|c|^n$, is your question how to show that $n|c|^n\to 0$?

Comment: Yeah. I can say there exists an index N such that $n|c|^n < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ where $\epsilon > 0$, but trying to work with this just keeps bringing up the product log function which I'm not allowed to use for this class yet which is why I'm trying a roundabout way by showing that $0$ is the greatest lower bound. @JonasMeyer

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that $n\geq2$, for $1|c|^1=|c|>0$.
Let $k=1/|c|$. Suppose that
$$n|c|^n>x>0$$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.
Then,
$$n>xk^n>0$$
Now, write $k=1+h$, $h>0$ and since $n\geq 2$,
$$n>x(1+h)^n>x+nhx+\frac{n^2-n}2h^2x$$
for all $n\in\Bbb N$. But $n$ is a first degree polynomial and the right side is a second degree poynomial whose main coefficient (namely $h^2x/2$) is positive. This is impossible.

BTW: Binomial theorem is often handy to prove that $a^n>p(n)$ when $a>1$, $p$ is a polynomial and $n$ is 'large enough'.

Comment: Where is your step "...and since n≥2..." coming from? 

So ultimately you're showing that logically deducing that a first-degree polynomial is larger than a second-degree one with a positive leading coefficient means that there's not an x strictly between n|c|n and 0 for all n∈N. This means that there's not a positive number strictly less than every term in the sequence which would make it the greatest lower bound, thus 0 must be the greatest lower bound. Right? @ajotatxe

Comment: @Owl_ First question: from the very beginning. Second question: yes, this is the point, essencially.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at all clear in what I meant. I should've asked where $x + nhx + (h^2x(n^2-n))/2$ came from because I'm not at all seeing that.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem to expand $(1+h)^n$. Look at the three first terms.

Comment: I thought that earlier but didn't work it out correctly. I put in $3$ for $n$ instead of leaving it as $n$. Just did it again and it makes complete sense now. Many thanks, it's greatly appreciated!